# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler

Tags: c#, mouseevent, double-click

In my program it is possible to draw a LinkLabel with the text which is defined before. When the LinkLabel is visible, I want to open a new form when I double click the LinkLabel

this is the code I have so far:

```
private Graphics g;

        private int punt1 = 0;
        private int punt2 = 0;

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = e.X;
            int y = e.Y;

            g = this.CreateGraphics();

            if (e.X > 20 && e.Y > 100)
            {
                ...

                if (rbTekst.Checked && MousePosition.X > 1000)
                {
                    string naam = tbUseCaseName.Text;
                    LinkLabel lb = new LinkLabel();
                    UseCase uc = new UseCase();
                    lb.MouseDoubleClick += uc.Show();
                    lb.Location = e.Location;
                    lb.Text = naam;
                    this.Controls.Add(lb);
                }
```

Everything works great except the DoubleClick event. I get the following error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler'

Does this error occurs because **Form1_MouseUp** has *MouseEventsArgs e*?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing the brackets on the `show` - `lb.MouseDoubleClick += uc.Show;`

Comment: That might be enough - it's hard to tell. What's the signature of `UseCase.Show`?

Comment: @petelids Nope: No overload for 'Show' matches delegate

Comment: @JonSkeet Expected a method with 'void Show(object, MouseEventsArgs)' signature

Comment: I'm asking what the `Show` method in `UseCase` looks like - you haven't shown us that.

Comment: how can I find that because I didn't define it myself, it's the build-in method to show another form that I want to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to assign the *result* of calling `uc.Show();` as the event handler for the `MouseDoubleClick` event. That method returns `void` which results in the error message you see.

If the signature** of `UseCase.Show` matches the expected signature of the event handler you can just assign the method itself:

```
lb.MouseDoubleClick += uc.Show;
```

Given your comments though it would appear that the signature doesn't match. In that case you could create an anonymous event handler that simply calls the method you want to call:

```
lb.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, e) =>  uc.Show();
```

Personally I prefer to enclose the method body in curly braces but it's not required:

```
lb.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, e) => { uc.Show(); };
```

You could also create a method to handle the click and call show from within there:

```
lb.MouseDoubleClick += lb_MouseDoubleClick;
...
void lb_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    uc.Show();
}
```

** The signature of a method is what the method looks like in terms of access modifiers, the return value and any parameters it accepts. I guess that `uc` is a `Form` in which case the `Show` method returns `void` and accepts no parameters. The `MouseDoubleClick` event expects a method that takes an `object` and a `MouseEventArgs`.

Comment: access modifiers and the return type are not parts of method signature

Comment: @ASh - that's not what it says on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173114.aspx) - _Methods are declared in a class or struct by specifying the access level such as public or private, optional modifiers such as abstract or sealed, the return value, the name of the method, and any method parameters. These parts together are the signature of the method._

Comment: `A return type of a method is not part of the signature of the method for the purposes of method overloading. However, it is part of the signature of the method when determining the compatibility between a delegate and the method that it points to.` well, my comment is off-topic in case of delegates

Comment: Bingo! Searched 2 days for your little remark concerning anonymous event handlers.